# Select pins by using Shapes in powerapps map

Tags: dictionary, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

i created an applicaton on powerapps but now i need to select the pins that are inside of a shape to store them in a data source. Any idea?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHEtN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the PowerApps [Geospatial interactive map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/geospatial-component-map) control.

[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/how-to/mobile-apps-address-map#map-control).

**Note:** The requires all users of the app to have a PowerApps premium license. You also have to provision a Dataverse database for the environment.